# vb6 text control when property set to multiline cannot hightlight text past box length, have to use right directional key

Tags: vb6, controls, highlighting, multiline

When I set the multiline property of the text control to true, when in use, if the text control is used as a basic one line textbox and the text typed in goes past the length of the box, it only highlights text up the end of the box, you have to press the right arrow key to highlight the rest. I need the multiline property set to true because in some scenarios it is necessary. I've thought of creating the text control twice with the property turned off in one and on in the other but wanted to know if anyone knew a solution?

Comment: I can't verify this as selecting all the text works fine for me. How are you selecting the text? If you will post your code it will help.

Comment: Is your "text control" `Edit` (VB6 `TextBox` control) or `RichEdit`? Does enabling horizontal scrolling for text control make the behavior you don't like to disappear?